# ruby on rails has_many validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Lets say there is an error in shirt. will the error appear also in person.errors ?
and if so, how can i reach it ? ( i don't want to use person.shirt.errors)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one   : shirt
      has_many  : pants
      validates :name, :presence => true
      validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 3
end

person = Person.new(:name => "JD")
person.shirt.create(:color=> "red")
person.pants.create(:type=> "jeans")
person.valid?
```

Comment: you're running the code, you can simply try it and see

Comment: Actually i am not running the code, i'm trying to learn about Ruby's errors mechanisem in order to implement it some place else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post it seems errors on child entities will be copied to the parent during a save, see [here -> Validations section](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms) although this might have been changed since

```
Validations simply work as you'd expect; 
#valid? will also validate nested models, 
#save(false) will save without validations, etc.

The only thing to note is that all error messages 
from the nested models are copied to the parent errors 
object for error_messages_for. This will probably change 
in the future, as discussed on the ticket, but that's 
outside of the scope of this patch.
```

Answer (score 0):

It should load into "person.errors". You can reach it by calling

```
person.errors.at(:<replace_this_with_name_of_attribute>)
```

You can also call

```
person.errors.each { |attr, msg| puts "attr = '#{attr}', msg = '#{msg}'" }
```

to check for all the error attribute names and the corresponding error messages. Good luck!

Comment: shirt is an has_many association. So, if the error is in shirt[2], i will reach the error by writing  person.errors.at(:shirt[2]) ?

Comment: if the error is within the shirt[2].color , the error will appear in person.errors.at(:shirt[2].color)  or person.errors.at(:shirt[2])  or prehaps both cases ? thx

Comment: someone has an answer for my last comment ?